# What is the $x$-intercept for $\frac{2x^2}{x^2-1} = 0$

Tags: calculus

I am sketching a curve and need to determine the $x$-intercept. Do I solve for the entire rational polynomial? The answer key states the $x$ intercept is $0$. I am wondering how it determined that. Work and an explanation are very welcomed.

Comment: what you have in your title is the equation you need to solve to find the x-intercepts, so just solve that equation, and you'll have them.

Comment: The book shows that I only use the numerator. Why?

Comment: because you can just multiply both sides by the denominator and it disappears.

Comment: Blood Pudding. What made you think to do that?

Comment: Thanks for the edit @user222031, I was just about to do it myself :P

Comment: clearing denominators is a common theme in algebraic simplification

Comment: Blood Pudding! You are speaking of multiplying both sides of the equation by zero since zero theoretically is the denominator of zero?

Comment: no, I'm referring to multiplying both sides by the denominator of the fraction $x^2 + 1$

Comment: Would you mind showing me or tell me what the method is called?

Comment: You called it clearing denominators and the method I have found implore the student to use multiply the denominator by the LCD of all the denominators

Answer (score 3):

Hint: ${a \over b}=0$ if and only if $a=0$ and $b\neq 0$.

Comment: Just to add, and $b\neq 0$ in the case $a$ and $b$ are functions of $x$.

Comment: so is it simply  0/-1?

Comment: The only way for the rational function to be $0$ is that the numerator is $0$.

Comment: correction: 'if and only if $a=0, b\neq 0$'. It is very important to add the condition that $b\neq 0$.

Comment: Added the condition $b\neq 0$. I'm not sure the downvote was really necessary though.

Comment: Reveillark.  I upvoted you.

Comment: I wasn't implying you were the downvoter, I'm sorry if it came out that way.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you know that the denominator cannot be zero (because you can't divide by zero), therefore the numerator has to be zero in order for the whole expression to be zero (0 divided by any number except zero, is zero or 0/a where a ∈ ℝ such that a ≠ 0).

Therefore, $\ 2x^2=0$
 
$\ x^2=0$ 
$\ x=0$

Answer (score 0):

More generally, if $g$ and $h$ are real-valued functions defined on some subset $S\subset\mathbb R$, and $$f(x) = \frac{g(x)}{h(x)}$$ for $x\in S$ such that $h(x)\ne0$, then for any fixed $x$, $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ are real numbers; say, $y$ and $z$. So from $\frac yz = yz^{-1} = 0$ we have that $y=0$, by multiplying by $z$.